# Django - Context not available in template tag include

Tags: jquery, python, django-forms, django-templates, django-context

```
<form class="signup" id="signup_form" method="post" action="{% url 'account_signup' %}">
   {{ form.subscription_year_plan }}
   <div class="page1"> {% include "account/signup_1.html" %} </div>
   <div class="page2"> {% include "account/signup_2.html" %} </div>
</form>
```

This is a part of my html. `{{ form.subscription_year_plan }}` is available outside and inside `signup_1.html` but not inside `signup_2.html`.

What'd be the problem?

Comment: There may be a typo in `signup_2.html`. Can you attach it's source?

Comment: Got it. I was trying to use `{{ form.subscription_year_plan }}` inside a `div` in signup_2.html which is being populated by ajax on document ready.

Comment: Can you add that as an answer and then accept it, so the question doesn't stay open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. I was trying to use `{{ form.subscription_year_plan }}` inside a div in signup_2.html which is being populated by ajax on document ready.